# Error using Spring Cloud Sleuth in Spring Webflux R2DBC project

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-sleuth, r2dbc

I am facing below error in spring WebFlux project(using R2DBC) after introducing `spring-cloud-sleuth` dependency and it started giving me these errors.

Java Version : 17

```
2023-05-11 12:48:43.618  INFO [,,] 18470 --- [           main] org.example.Application                  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-05-11 12:48:44.188  INFO [,,] 18470 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data R2DBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-05-11 12:48:44.344  INFO [,,] 18470 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 151 ms. Found 1 R2DBC repository interfaces.
2023-05-11 12:48:44.650 ERROR [,,] 18470 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.cloud.commons.httpclient.HttpClientConfiguration]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:334) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:474) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:397) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:283) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:106) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:285) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:103) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:82) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitionForImportedConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:150) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.example.Application.main(Application.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.commons.httpclient.HttpClientConfiguration
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:495) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:324) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

After adding debug point shows error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax/management/remote/rmi/RMIServerImpl_Skel
java.rmi.server.SkeletonNotFoundException: Skeleton class not found: javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl_Skel; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax/management/remote/rmi/RMIServerImpl_Skel
```

Another error after following breakpoint is

```
null KeyStore name
```

As soon as I remove spring cloud sleuth dependency, it works again.

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Don't use  spring cloud sleuth dependency

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, So what should I use ? Micrometer ?

Comment: Sounds like a new question.

Comment: your error is probably because of you missmatching versions etc in your maven file, but @K.Nicholas is right, sleuth uses `ThreadLocal` and you can't use libraries that use `ThreadLocal` in reactive programming. Why you might ask, thats too long to explain here but here is a blog post about why https://spring.io/blog/2023/03/28/context-propagation-with-project-reactor-1-the-basics